# Android Installation failure - Not enough space - Error Code -4

Tags: android, installation, apk

One of my users is reporting that he can not install my app anymore. He uninstalled the app and when he tried to reinstall it he gets an error like "Not enough storage".

According to his descriptions, he can install other apps just fine, regardless of size (My .apk is ~1MB).

The user is running Android 2.3.6. The same error occurs if he uses the .apk I send him instead of using Google Play.

This is an excerpt of the LogCat he send me, app name is replaced with com.myApp.Foo

Money Quote: "1.packageInstalled: Package install status for "com.myApp.Foo" is -4"

```
D/Finsky (29919): [23] 7.run: Enqueued com.myApp.Foo as content://downloads/my_downloads/610
D/Finsky (29919): [1] DownloadImpl.setState: com.myApp.Foo from QUEUED to DOWNLOADING.
D/Finsky (29919): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.onStart: com.myApp.Foo: onStart
D/Finsky (29919): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.notifyProgress: com.myApp.Foo: onProgress 0/-1 Status: 190.
D/DownloadManager(29988): mime type is null
D/Finsky (29919): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.notifyProgress: com.myApp.Foo: onProgress 0/-1 Status: 192.
I/DownloadManager(29988): Initiating request for download 610
D/ConnectivityService( 226): in getAllNetworkInfo: mNetworksDefined=9, result count=6
I/DownloadManager(29988): Initiating request for download 610
D/ConnectivityService( 226): in getAllNetworkInfo: mNetworksDefined=9, result count=6
W/ActivityManager( 226): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.providers.downloads.action.Dispatch typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive (has extras) }: not found
D/Finsky (29919): [1] DetailsDataBasedFragment.rebindViews: Page [class=DetailsFragment] loaded in [9465 ms] (partial? false)
D/LatinKeyboard( 307): updateF1Key-mIsAlphaKeyboard: true ,mHasVoiceButton: true
D/Finsky (29919): [1] DetailsDataBasedFragment.rebindViews: Page [class=DetailsFragment] loaded in [9755 ms] (partial? true)
W/Finsky (29919): [1] CarrierParamsAction.run: Saving carrier billing params failed.
D/Finsky (29919): [1] GetBillingCountriesAction.run: Skip getting fresh list of billing countries.
E/Finsky (29919): [32] FileBasedKeyValueStore.delete: Attempt to delete 'params57V5ZrspGc4ULD9_G0atJg' failed!
D/Finsky (29919): [1] DownloadBroadcastReceiver.onReceive: Intent received at DownloadBroadcastReceiver
D/Finsky (29919): [1] DownloadImpl.setState: com.myApp.Foo from DOWNLOADING to SUCCESS.
D/Finsky (29919): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.onComplete: com.myApp.Foo: onComplete
D/Finsky (29919): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.remove: Download com.myApp.Foo removed from DownloadQueue
I/ActivityManager( 226): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=30008 uid=10019 gids={1015, 2001}
I/ActivityManager( 226): Process de.gdp (pid 29754) has died.
W/ActivityManager( 226): Scheduling restart of crashed service de.gdp/com.urbanairship.push.PushService in 5000ms
I/ActivityManager( 226): Low Memory: No more background processes.
W/ActivityManager( 226): No content provider found for:
W/ActivityManager( 226): No content provider found for:
D/PackageParser( 226): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl2041276702.tmp
D/Finsky (29919): [8] 1.packageInstalled: Package install status for "com.myApp.Foo" is -4
D/Finsky (29919): [1] InstallerTask.cancelCleanup: Cancel running installation of com.myApp.Foo
I/TiApplication(30017): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, app created.
I/ActivityManager( 226): Process com.android.defcontainer (pid 30008) has died.
I/ActivityManager( 226): Low Memory: No more background processes.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is on your end - it sounds like the clients Android is borked.

I suspect one or several of your clients installed apps are hogging either cache or data storage. Ask him/her to go to Settings -> Apps -> All (or equivalent on 2.3.6) and clear data for one or more of the top apps in the list, by selecting an app, and selecting "Clear Data" & "Clear Cache".

After he/she has done this, the install should work as it should.

Comment: I think you are right, this should not caused by an issue inside the .apk. Data storage does not seem to be a problem as he stated that he can install other apps that are bigger without problems. I don't know about the cache part. I am going to forward your suggestions to the user, see if it helps.

Answer (score -2):

select your project --> right click --> refresh --> then select Project tab --> select Clean --> run your app

(Just one suggestion before posting question first surf related question)

Comment: I don't get how this is relevant to this problem. Please clarify.

Comment: this problem may be due to R.java file creation.

and yeah first also uninstall your app from emulator,
still you are getting error uninstall some other unnecessary app,
increase memory of emulator if needed.

Comment: the installation file is fine, its just one user that is having this issue. There are thousand of users that can install my app without problems. There is no mention of the emulator in my post. storage is also not an issue, as I stated in the question. Please read the question before posting an answer.

Comment: have you tried above mentioned things....
even if it is not working u r getting anything new ??

Comment: Again, please read the question.  But if it makes you feel better: I have done countless project cleans and deployed two new versions to Google Play since the user first had this problem. Again, this not caused by a faulty installation file.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got -1,
i have faces this issue and this solution worked for me even I have seen this answer on SO.
If it is not applicable to someone it doesn't mean it is wrong...

Comment: It is not wrong, it is just not relevant to this question. But I agress, a -1 is a bit harsh imho :)